# Index of New Item from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I created an editable JComboBox (in a JTable, if that matters).

```
JComboBox<String> eventBox=new JComboBox<String>(Configuration.getInstance().getEventList());
timeLineDialog.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(eventBox));
timeLineDialog.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxCellRenderer(eventBox));
eventBox.setEditable(true);
eventBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + eventBox.getSelectedItem());
        System.out.println(", Position: " + eventBox.getSelectedIndex());
    }

});
```

By observation I've noticed that the index of the selected item, when it does not yet exist after editing, is -1. Is this a reliable way to determine a new item or must I do an actual search of the list to avoid duplicates? TIA.

Comment: I think "No selection" also returns -1. `Is this a reliable way to determine a new item or must I do an actual search of the list to avoid duplicates?` probably a reliable way to determine an tem that has not been added, but surely not to avoid duplicates

Comment: Would no selection even trigger an action?

Comment: Not by default, but if you have a button which resets the selection, then an `SelectionEvent` should be triggered. `ActionEvent` is only on click

Comment: Thanks. I guess I do need to check the list for duplicates then.

Comment: It turns out that if one types an existing item, the combobox is smart enough to recognize that and returns the proper index. No need to check for duplicates.